# Powershell use "-match" to compare to an array?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to check if something inside the Array matches $File.FullName, but as soon as I use an Array, it returns nothing anymore.

How can I solve this?

EDIT: I eventually want to use it inside an if statement, so just making another foreach is no option.

Example:

```
$Test = Get-ChildItem -Path "Some\Path" | Select-Object -Property FullName, Length, LastWriteTime
foreach($File in $Test)
{
    if($File.FullName -match $ArrayofStringsThings)
    {
        echo $File
    }
```

}

Comment: "Matches" how? Literal matches can be done with `-in`, but if the array is an array of wildcards, you'll need something more complicated (like `$array.Where{$File.FullName -match $_}`). Also, since you're using `Get-ChildItem`, you can possibly get what you want much simpler by using its `-Include` switch.

Comment: -in and -contains whould probably work if it would be exactly the same. But what if I want "thisis" to match "is". An whats the difference between them?

Comment: Well then, like I said, `if (@("is", "this", "sparta").Where{"thisis" -match $_}) { "This is at least somewhat Sparta" }`. (Also try "athens" instead of "thisis".) While you can't put `foreach` in an `if`, it does allow arbitrary expressions, including things like "the list of all things that matched", and those are truthy when not empty.

Comment: Thanks! Worked great!

Answer (score 3):

This will work, though it isn't a well designed function and there are many ways to create a smaller/simpler ad hoc method:

```
$Test = Get-ChildItem -Path * | Select-Object -Property FullName, Length, LastWriteTime
$Patterns = 'Get','Csv','Storage'
$Width = -1 * ((measure-object -maximum length).maximum + 1) 
foreach($File in $Test) {
  ForEach ($Pattern in $Patterns) {
    If ($File.FullName -match $Pattern) {   # Check each pattern
      write-warning ("Match: {0,$Width} {1}" -f $Pattern, $File.FullName)
      $File
      break # already matched so no need to check this file further
    } 
  }
}
```

This will work as well:

```
$Test     = Get-ChildItem -Path *
$Patterns = 'Get', 'CSV', 'Storage' 
$Test | Where-Object { $_.FullName -Match ('(' + ($Patterns -join ')|(') + ')' ) }
```

Just ignoring the Select-Object properties and leaving the original objects intact. 
(Properties can be selected after the filtering completes giving more flexibility.)

Or perhaps this is easier to read and modify:

```
$Test            = Get-ChildItem -Path *
$Patterns        = 'Get', 'CSV', 'Storage' 
$CombinedPattern = '(' + ($Patterns -join ')|(' ) + ')'
$Test | Where-Object { $_.FullName -Match $CombinedPattern }
```

Comment: When the left-hand side of `-match` is an array, the operator will filter the list using the pattern. For example:

PS[1] (172) > "a", "b", "c", "d" -match "b|c"
b
c
PS[1] (173) > "a", "b", "c", "d" -match "notThere"
PS[1] (174) > [bool] ("a", "b", "c", "d" -match "b|c")
True
PS[1] (175) > [bool] ("a", "b", "c", "d" -match "notFound")
False

Comment: Sorry about the messed up formatting. Let's try again. When the left-hand side of `-match` is an array, the operator will filter the list using the pattern. For example:
`"a", "b", "c", "d" -match "b|c"` results in `b c` and `"a", "b", "c", "d" -match "notThere"` gives `$null`
Cast as a boolean  `[bool] ("a", "b", "c", "d" -match "b|c")` gives you `$true` and 
`[bool] ("a", "b", "c", "d" -match "notFound")` gives you $false

Answer (score -1):

From the following page [about_comparison_operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-Microsoft.PowerShell.Core)

> The -match operators **search only in strings**. *They cannot search in arrays of integers or other objects*.

What you can use:

> -contains :   Returns true when reference value contained in a collection
>
> -notcontains : Returns true when reference value not contained in a collection
>
> -in :  Returns true when test value contained in a collection
>
> -notin :   Returns true when test value not contained in a collection

Let me explain how you could have known it was returning an array:

When you would use the following command:

```
$test | gm
```

It would present you the following output

`TypeName: Selected.System.IO.DirectoryInfo`

If you then google that typename you end up at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3e2f6e5(v=vs.110).aspx

When you then look at the page you'll find:

> Return Value
>
> Type: System.IO.DirectoryInfo[]
>
> **An array** of type DirectoryInfo matching searchPattern.

Comment: It would only be an array ***if*** there are more than one items in the folder. As a matter of fact if you do `$test | gm` Then Get-Member will tell you the members for the first item in the array. It will not only not tell you that $test is an array, if $test actually is an array it will tell you about the single item that is the first item in the array. There are a few ways to tell if a variable holds an array. `$test.GetType()` will tell you that it is an Object[] which indicates an array of objects.

Comment: Hi EBGreen,If i were to use `$test | gm`  then i wouldn't know that it's an array just based off the information it shows me. if i use `$test |  select *  | gm` it will tell me that it's a pscustomobject and thus an array. Or am i missing something?

Comment: PSCustom object is not an array. It is an object. Period. You can have an array of PSCustomObjects, but the objects themselves are not arrays. You can have a PSCustomObject that has an array for one of it's properties but the PSCuctomObject is still just a single object not an array.

Comment: This statement "The -match operators search only in strings. They cannot search in arrays of integers or other objects." is not correct. Please open an issue on this document. The `-match` operator most certainly does search in arrays. Thanks.

Comment: @BrucePayette you are correct as long as the powershell version is recent enough.

Comment: @BrucePayette I've send feedback on the article. Do i need to remove my post ?